# Convert HTML to base64 in nodejs with special characters

Tags: node.js, base64

I have created an api to convert html file to base64 string like this

```
let base64File = new Buffer.from(req.file.path, 'utf8').toString('base64');
```

It works normally with simple html file , but when it comes to html file with special characters example like : "«", "Â",... it changed to � when i write back to html. I noticed that i tried using online tool like https://codebeautify.org  , it returns different result from mine (but the result proviedd by it write back to html normally) but same result for simple html file.How can i convert correctly?

Comment: If you base64 encode something, and then base64 decode it you should always get the same string. The issue probably has to do with how you display the HTML (and where) and not with encoding.

Comment: i compared mine result with online result its different , but when it comes to normal file without special character it return the same result , i tested it many time.

Comment: *something* is different in how you encode the data. The difference is not in base64 itself. If you want more help with this, try edit your question and give an example I (and everyone else) can run so we can validate what you're doing.

Comment: If the problem is "when i write back to html", then show that code. With enough [mcve] code around it to show that a hardcoded bit of HTML with unicode in it _actually_ turns into something garbled. The code you're showing is perfectly fine, that's not where the problem you're talking about is.